# qt4 scons including a uic file in variant_dir

Tags: c++, qt4, scons

I'm using the qt4 tool for scons and having some troubles getting the `.ui` files to be handled correctly. *I'm coming from a Cmake background with Qt and a beginner with scons.*

In my SConstruct file I have

```
env.Uic4(Glob('*.ui'))
env.Program('test',Glob('*.cpp'))
```

The problem is that my source file can't find the resulting header files `src/qt-test/sample_widget.cpp:3:23: error: ui_sample.h: No such file or directory`. The header file **is** created, as is all moc processing done, thus I'm pretty sure everything is installed correctly and basically correct.

What I think is happening is because this is a recrusive SConstruct file, and the caller is using a `variant_dir` for the build. So possibly the problem is just getting the compiler to resolve headers in the build directory (and perhaps nothing to do with the qt4 tool). This was handled automatically in CMake (I think).

So how do I get this working (get the ui include file to be found)?

Comment: Where did you get the qt4 implementation? Im interested in doing some qt4 dev and found this: https://bitbucket.org/dirkbaechle/scons_qt4 It seems like the latest.

Comment: @Brady, I believe that is the one I have.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CPPPATH construction variable to set the include paths as mentioned in the man pages:

http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/a4916.html

For example:

```
env.Append(CPPPATH = ['dir1', 'dir2'])
```

Brady

Comment: The problem is in this file I don't know what the directory will be, some parent SConstruct file set the variant directory. The parent file also can't simply add every single output directory to the path.

Comment: According to the SCons man page description of uic() : 'Builds a header file, an implementation file and a moc file from an ui file. and returns the corresponding nodes in the above order.'
So you should be able to use the returned nodes to get the paths. Or pass the header file node to the CPPPATH statement mentioned above.

Comment: One clarification on my last comment: Instead of passing the header file node, you'll have to call the abspath() function on that particular node when passing it to CPPPATH